# Can I compose variable to create new varibales in Postman?

Tags: api, rest, automated-tests, postman, web-api-testing

I have a variable as `BASE_URL`. When I am using the `localhost`, I am composing it with one more variable `PORT` that reflects the port on which the service is running on my local. These two variables composed as `{{BASE_URL}}:{{PORT}}` defines the complete base URL for my APIs.

But when testing the deployed version of my API, my base URL is just `https://www.xyzapi.com` without any port declared explicitly.

I am using `{{BASE_URL}}/rule-service/v1/find-by-txn` format in the request URL. I am using environments to switch between `local` and `remote`.

How can I utilize the same request format for both cases? I have multiple microservices running on different ports.

Comment: You can include the port number in your BASE_URL variable. Example: 
BASE_URL = localhost:8080 in your local environment.

Comment: But I will have multiple URLs. Wanted to know if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It introduces a variabe `FINAL_BASE_URL` which is to be used to build your URLs (eg `{{FINAL_BASE_URL}}/rule-service/v1/find-by-txn`) and it includes the `PORT` or not, depending if an environment variable `PORT` is set.

```
if (pm.environment.get("PORT")) { 
    let FINAL_BASE_URL = pm.environment.get("BASE_URL") + ":" + pm.environment.get("PORT")
} else {
    let FINAL_BASE_URL = pm.environment.get("BASE_URL")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used a similar approach and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This code did the job!

```
let baseUrl = pm.environment.get("BASE_URL");

if(baseUrl.includes('localhost')){
    let port = pm.collectionVariables.get("PORT");
    baseUrl = baseUrl.split(':')[0];
    baseUrl = `${baseUrl}:${port}`;
}

pm.environment.set("BASE_URL", baseUrl);
```